# Creating Maven dependency of Project A and using it in Project B

Tags: java, maven

I have a maven Spring boot project for which I've created a jar to use as a dependency externally in other projects. I just can't get it to work. Here are my steps.

Here is my pom.xml for Project 1.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>org.myapp.logmonitoring</groupId>
<artifactId>logmonitoring</artifactId>
<name>logmonitoring</name>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.5</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-web -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-tomcat -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.awaitility/awaitility -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.awaitility</groupId>
        <artifactId>awaitility</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-test -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.6</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test-jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
            <finalName>logmonitoring/logmonitoring-app</finalName>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

And this is my pom.xml for Project 2. It just doesn't work.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>org.myapp.logmonitoring.host1</groupId>
<artifactId>logmonitoring-host1</artifactId>
<name>logmonitoring-host1</name>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.myapp.logmonitoring</groupId>
        <artifactId>logmonitoring</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Have you tried doing `mvn clean install` for the first project, and then `mvn clean install` for the second project? What error messages are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

You have to put Jar as well as pom file of 1st project in.m2 repository.

> .m2/org/myapp/logmonitoring/1.0-SNAPSHOT.

then add dependency like this

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.myapp</groupId>
        <artifactId>logmonitoring</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
```

If you are using mac then you can find .m2 repository in

> /Users/<user_name>/.m2.

In Windowns it's in

> C:\Users<User_Name>.m2

In linux it's in

> /home/<User_Name>/.m2

Also unhide Hidden files

Answer (score 0):

This really helped me solve it - http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-add-a-project-as-a-dependency-of-another-project.html